# How to custom scrollbars using input type=range

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there a way to custom a scrollbar by using input type=range?

i know there is a way to custom scrollbar by webkit scrollbar, but i also want it to work on firefox.

so far, what I have is this

https://codepen.io/sir-j/pen/NWggGde

I basically linked my  `$(window).scrollTop()` to the value of whatever the range is.

the problem with this is that my browser can scroll up and down when i change the range, but i cannot change the input range when i scroll up and down.

anyone has any idea?

Comment: There’s the [`scroll` event](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event).

Comment: @SebastianSimon how do I change the vlaue of the input range together with it though? please check my code pen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use scroll event and window.scrollY to getting scroll value

P.S. This is code with two way binding, you must only synchronize that:

```
var i = document.querySelector('input')

i.addEventListener('input', function () {
  const num = parseNum(i.value);
  document.getElementById('thescrolling2').innerHTML =  num;
  $(window).scrollTop(num);
})

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  i.value = parseNum(window.scrollY);
  windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  document.getElementById('thescrolling1').innerHTML = parseNum(windowScrollTop);
}, false);

function parseNum(v) {
  return Number(v).toFixed(2);
}
```

[scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)

Comment: how do i change the value of range input together with it though?

Comment: thanks! that worked. but whats the difference between using window.addEventListener('scroll') first, and using i.addEventListener('input') first?